# How can I develop Qt apps for desktop environment using NokiaQtSDK?

Tags: qt, sdk, qt-creator

I have started using Qt. I have installed NokiaQtSDK for Qt development. But I can't develop Qt apps for desktop using this SDK. What I have to do to develop Qt apps for desktop environment using NokiaQtSDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt development environments downloaded from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/ should give you everything you need.  They allow you to develop for several environments, including Desktop, Symbian, and even Maemo.

In Qt Creator, you can select the target environment by selecting the computer icon in the bottom righthand corner.

Answer (score 0):

NokiaQtSDK is meant for developing apps for Symbian smartphones, not desktops.

Comment: Thanks Riho. Can you point me to any Qt SDK which is capable of developing symbian and desktop app? If there is none, then can I add symbian development SDK with desktop developmentSDK for same Qt creator?

Comment: I never tried desktop development. Go to Qt homep age and search around.